# Latex complex number symbol ℂ in text

Tags: symbols, characters

I want to write $\mathbb{C}$ as a text in my references (.bib) file. it is a text and it is not inside math dollar.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Your question isn't very clear. Is there any reason why you can't just put `$\mathbb{C}$` into your `.bib` file entry? (Assuming this is what you mean by 'references'). If not, you'll need to show us more clearly what you're doing. Also if you're using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX you could just use the character directly assuming the font you're using as a text font contains it.

Comment: @AlanMunn yes in .bib file.

Comment: Welcome. // AFAIK it‘s not available in the ASCII sets. So you ask for a font. The math mode you mentioned is one of them. See e.g. page 93 in https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf#page93 for other font options in LaTeX. It mentions some more.